# How can I style exercises like that?

Tags: book-design, exercises

How can I style exercises like the one in this book but the exercises numbers should not follow the theorems numbers.

[image]

This page is from Lee's introduction to topological manifolds.

Comment: Looks pretty !!

Comment: @Tarass Yes. I usually use`\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]` and I get something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oWKbo.png). The exercises have exactly the same style as the theorems which isn't pretty.

Comment: There is sevrel ways. do you plan to use `amsthm` or `ntheorem` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is  a solution with the `ntheorem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
{
\theoremprework{\vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep\relax\par\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}\small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\theoremindent 2.5em
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{exercise}[prop]{Exercise}
}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3}
\begin{prop}\label{myprop}
  Blah blah blah.
\end{prop}

\begin{proof} [of \cref{myprop}]Since something is true, we have
  \[ A = B. \]
\end{proof}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{exercise}
  Prove the preceding proposition. Prove the preceding proposition. Prove the preceding proposition. Prove the preceding proposition.
\end{exercise}

Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\begin{proof}[of some theorem]
  This is a very important proof. Isn't it?
  \begin{align*}
    a & = b \\ c & = d.
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Added:$$ Here is a corrected code. The problem came froma conflict with `hyperef`. I reorganised the order of the theorems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, francais, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding} % for checkmarks and XSolidBrush in itemize http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref, hyperref]{ntheorem}
 \usepackage[pdftex,pdfauthor={Elie Nasrallah}, pdftitle={Mathematiques Elementaires}, pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}, bookmarks, bookmarksopen, bookmarksnumbered, pdfstartview={FitH}, colorlinks, linkcolor={blue}, citecolor={blue}, urlcolor={red}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\upshape\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Exemple}[chapter]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remarque}[chapter]
\theoremprework{\vskip\dimexpr\topsep+\partopsep \relax\par\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}\small\vspace*{\dimexpr-\topsep-\baselineskip}\leavevmode}
\theoremindent 2.5em
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}

\newtheorem{proof}{Démonstration}
\newtheorem{solution}{S}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Fonction réelle d'une variable réelle}

\section{Limites et asymptotes}

\begin{proposition}
Si $f(x)<g(x)$ sur un voisinage de $x_0$ alors $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)$.
 \end{proposition}


\begin{exercise}
wfsafasfaf
\end{exercise}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I says file heuristica.sty not found.

Comment: That is not essential: it is a font package for text, which is an extension of `Adobe Utopia` (on which `fourier` is based). It adds true small caps, superior and inferior numbers. It's in the preamble just because I built my code starting from an old file of mine. You can remove it, or install it. If you want to install, note it's still better to install `erewhon` instead, from the same author.

Comment: It's a problem with hyperref,  it was necessary to add the option `hyperref` to `ntheorem`, and load `hyperref *before* the first theorem declaration. Furthermore, your theorem declarations were placed in such a way that they all would be displayed in upshape font and all would have an end-of-proof symbol. I suppose this is not what you want. See (and understand) the corrected code. Another comment: `times` is obsolete. If you want to use this font, load `mathptmx`, or better `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. In the meantime, I let fourier, which you'll have to remove if you want to use times.

Comment: You're welcome. For theorems layout, you should take a look at the documentation of `ntheorem`. Also, at the `cleveref` documentation, it can help saving some typing for cross-references.